# How do I open and close a Material-UI Dialog in Meteor/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, material-design, material-ui

I'm trying to have a dialog with a form pop up when the user clicks a button. I pretty much took exactly from the [Dialog Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dialog) site for how to do this with a button that will be used to open the Dialog and a TextField added in the Dialog. This is using Meteor and React. When I run on the server I get an error. Anyone know what `Missing class properties transform.` means?

**Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton';
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const style = {
  marginRight: "20px",
  position: "absolute",
  left: "80%",
  down: "80%",
};

export default class Events extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({open: false});
  };

  render() {
    const actions = [
          <FlatButton
            label="Cancel"
            primary={true}
            onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
          />,
          <FlatButton
            label="Submit"
            primary={true}
            keyboardFocused={true}
            onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
          />,
        ];

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Events</h1>
          <FloatingActionButton style={style}>
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>
          <Dialog
            title="Add Event"
            actions={actions}
            model={false}
            open={this.state.open}
            onRequestClose={this.handClose}
          >
            <TextField
              hintText="Hint Text"
              floatingLabelText="Floating Label Text"
            />
          </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Errors prevented startup:

While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
client/events/Events.jsx:20:2: /client/events/Events.jsx: Missing class properties transform.

Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my other answer for making this code work, but you can also avoid using the class syntax entirely if you'd prefer.

```
import React from 'react';
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton';
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const style = {
  marginRight: "20px",
  position: "absolute",
  left: "80%",
  down: "80%",
};


export default const Events = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      open: false
    }
  },
  handleOpen: () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
  },

  handleClose: () => {
    this.setState({open: false});
  },

  render: function() {
    const actions = [
          <FlatButton
            label="Cancel"
            primary={true}
            onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
          />,
          <FlatButton
            label="Submit"
            primary={true}
            keyboardFocused={true}
            onTouchTap={this.handleClose}
          />,
        ];

    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Events</h1>
          <FloatingActionButton style={style}>
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>
          <Dialog
            title="Add Event"
            actions={actions}
            model={false}
            open={this.state.open}
            onRequestClose={this.handClose}
          >
            <TextField
              hintText="Hint Text"
              floatingLabelText="Floating Label Text"
            />
          </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using babel, you need the [class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) transform. It is included in the [stage 2 preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/) if that's more preferable. Are you bundling using webpack? Sharing your webpack config, especially the `js`/`jsx` section in `loaders` would be helpful.

Comment: I think my issue is babel. I've seen that many times looking into this issue and I've also looked at their documentation. I don't know what it is and didn't think it was needed as it's not mentioned in the Dialog part of Material-UI. Would I just need babel-cli using `npm install --save babel-cli`?

Comment: Sharing your webpack config would be really helpful here. You're probably already using babel, but you have to specify which plugins you need. Do you have anything like babel in your package.json, or do you have a .babelrc file?

Comment: And then add the `.babelrc` to the root of the project?

Comment: I do not have a `.babelrc` nor babel in my package.json.

Comment: How are you building or executing your javascript file?

Comment: Meteor does all of the building and execution.

Comment: Try my other answer below, you can avoid this whole babel mess if you'd rather :)